# 'an expression of non boolean type specified' in CASE WHEN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given this T-SQL code:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN ( Cast (CASE 
                        WHEN Isnull(bpe.new, 0) = 0 
                             AND Isnull(bpe.regular, 0) = 0 
                             AND Isnull(bpe.bargain, 0) = 0 THEN 0 
                        ELSE 1 
                      END AS BIT) 
                AND @siteID IS NULL 
                 OR bpe.siteid = @siteID ) THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END AS SiteHasBrandException 
FROM   brandpromoexceptions AS bpe
```

I get the error message:

> an expression of non boolean type specified in the context where a condition is expected TSQL

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean zero as "false" for that first bit, the query should be equivalent to:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
NOT ( ISNULL(bpe.new, 0) = 0 
      AND Isnull(bpe.regular, 0) = 0 
      AND Isnull(bpe.bargain, 0) = 0 )
AND ( @siteID IS NULL 
      OR bpe.siteid = @siteID )
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 
END AS SiteHasBrandException 
FROM brandpromoexceptions AS bpe
```

You may need to be careful with that "OR" clause, or add parentheses for clarification.  I guessed here.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your first `CASE` statement a call to `CAST` rather than a conditional.  The error message pretty much spells it out.

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but you seem to understand that you need to pass a boolean to the `CASE WHEN` based on your subsequent use of `CASE` so hopefully this helps.

this is a shot in the dark by try changing your code to this:

```
SELECT CASE 
     WHEN ( Cast (CASE 
                    WHEN Isnull(bpe.new, 0) = 0 
                         AND Isnull(bpe.regular, 0) = 0 
                         AND Isnull(bpe.bargain, 0) = 0 THEN 0 
                    ELSE 1 
                  END AS BIT) = 1
            AND @siteID IS NULL 
             OR bpe.siteid = @siteID ) THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 
   END AS SiteHasBrandException 
FROM   brandpromoexceptions AS bpe
```